# Random HTML accent encoding issues

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I have one problem when using accents in HTML. The problem is that my page is loaded sometimes with all characters ok and sometimes with the typical strange characters like Ã, only need to refresh the page to load ok or wrong... this is absolutely random but first time after clean cache is always bad loaded.

Of course I have the meta line in headers

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>"
```

The file have php extension, don't know if this is relevant but I include the next two lines in the php section:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're using Notepad++, go to Encoding and select "Convert to UTF-8". Then save your file and try again

Answer (score 0):

Those settings tell the browser what encoding you say you are using but doesn't change your encoding itself,

if your data is not utf8 encoded you need to encode it in your code using something like the utf8_encode() function or the mb_convert_encoding() function.

you can use the function mb_detect_encoding() to find out what encoding your data is in, en then encode accordingly.